# How to create recursion in AWS Step Functions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

How to create step which will be repeated if lambda function will return "failed" status.

```
job2 = job1.next(Choice(self, "Check status.").when(Condition.number_equals("$.statusCode", 200), job3).otherwise(job2))
```

Comment: Probably not the best idea to keep repeating a step that's failing, in case it never succeeds. You should limit the number of retries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Choice` state should have 3 branches:

1. if `job1` succeeded, go to `job2`
2. if `job1` failed AND a retry count has not been reached, loop `incrementTask -> job1`
3. otherwise go to the `Fail` state

```py
checkStatus = (
    sfn.Choice(self, "CheckStatus")
    .when(sfn.Condition.number_equals("$.job1.statusCode", 200), job2)
    .when(
        sfn.Condition.and_(
            sfn.Condition.not_(sfn.Condition.number_equals("$.job1.statusCode", 200)),
            sfn.Condition.or_(
                sfn.Condition.is_not_present("$.retryCount"),
                sfn.Condition.number_less_than("$.retryCount", 3),
            ),
        ),
        incrementTask.next(job1),
    )
    .otherwise(fail)
)
```

Add a Lambda Task that increments the retry count before looping back to `job1`.  Make sure to set a `result_path` on `job1` so that it does not overwrite the `retryCount`.

```py
# incrementTask handler
def handler(event, context):
      event["retryCount"] = event.get("retryCount", 0) + 1
      return event
```

The state machine will look like this:

[image: state machine]

Comment: This is totally possible, but I would add a warning to anyone attempting this with anything more complex than a basic single retry loop like this: don't. This example is completely simple enough to be manageable, anything more complex you're better off leveraging the Dead Letter Queue from failed Lambda's (or a fail state catch in the Step Function itself) and an SQS queue to re-fire the StepFunction when you want to control it.

Comment: Does this actually work? In `incrementTask.next(job1)` how does this instance of `job1` know that it should proceed to `checkStatus` as its next state?

Comment: Can confirm this works :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot internally to just Step Function... or more accurately, there *may* be a way but if you do go down that rather complex and overly complicated path you are going to set yourself to be charged 1000s of dollars as a failed lambda causes the system to rerun continuously and charging you every time.

You can do something with a Dead Letter Queue or a Catch in your Step Function definition to add an even too an SQS queue and have that fire every so often to re start failed jobs. But again. Be careful. It would be very easy to end up charging yourself/your company thousand of dollars very easily