# How can I use a Task State multiple times in AWS Step Functions using the CDK?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

For example I have 3 lambdas :

```py
    sfn_step_1 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "1st-one",
                                            lambda_function=1st-one ,
                                            output_path="$.Payload",
                                            payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                                "payload.$": "$",
                                    
                                            })
                                            )
    
     sfn_step_2 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "2nd-One",
                                            lambda_function=2nd-One,
                                            output_path="$.Payload",
                                            payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                                "payload.$": "$",
                                     
                                            })
                                            )
    
     sfn_step_3 = tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "3rd-one",
                                            lambda_function=3rd-one,
                                            output_path="$.Payload",
                                            payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                                "payload.$": "$",
                                          
                                            })
                                            )
```

I want to reuse states 2 and 3 each two times: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 2 -> 3`

So I am trying to do this:

```py
     state_machine_definition = sfn_step_1.next(sfn_step_2).next(sfn_step_3).next(sfn_step_2).\
                next(sfn_step_3)
```

but I'm getting this issue:

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: State '2nd-One' already has a next state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially telling Step Functions to loop infinitely between Steps 2 and 3.  That's invalid.  Hence the error: Task States can only have one "next" (outbound) path.  Fortunately, you can solve your problem simply, without recursion.<sup>*</sup>

Write a factory function that returns a Lambda Task, passing an id and the function reference.  Call the factory function multiple times to build the state machine.  This gives you DRY repeating tasks without recursion.

```py
# Task Factory
def make_step(id: str, func: _lambda.Function) -> tasks.LambdaInvoke:
    return tasks.LambdaInvoke(
        self,
        id,
        lambda_function=func,
        payload_response_only=True,
        result_path=f"$.{id}",
    )

sfn.StateMachine(
      self,
      "RepeatStepsMachine",
      definition=make_step("step_1", 1st_One)
      .next(make_step("step_2", 2nd_One))
      .next(make_step("step_3", 3rd_One))
      .next(make_step("step_2b", 2nd_One))
      .next(make_step("step_3b", 3rd_One).next(sfn.Succeed(self, "Done"))),
  )
```

*  If required, [recursion can be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72777397/1103511) with a Choice State.  Choice States are designed to have multiple "outbound" paths.  It's not the best fit for your use case, though.

Comment: on deploying now getting  `Policy statement must contain resources. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; St
atus Code: 400; `

Comment: @back-new That is an unrelated error.  Try deploying a minimal State Machine that has only one Task (e.g. use your `sfn_step_1`).  Once that succeeds, apply the pattern in the answer.

Comment: @back-new I tested the answer before posting. I can confirm that it deploys and runs successfully.  The only code not shown is my `_lambda.Function` definition.

Comment: Working now thanks. I was passing wrongly sfn_step_1 thi . just one last thing I want in end to get True just instead of this done. like    `"End": true`

Comment: @back-new Glad it's working for you.  The final `Succeed` State is optional.

Comment: Thanks sir , and can you please take a look on this issue if this is possible ? thanks in advance   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823008/is-this-possible-to-extend-api-gateway-apis-using-python-cdk