# step function input issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cdk

Hi my step function cdk code is something like this

```
tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, "my_step_function",
                                        lambda_function=my_lambda,
                                        output_path="$.Payload",
                                        payload=stepfunctions.TaskInput.from_object({
                                            "payload.$": "$",
                                            "job_id.$": "$$.Job.Id"
                                        })
```

and when doing post  request I am  sending request like this :

```
scan_resp = requests.post(BASE_URL + '/start', json={'job_id': job_id},
                              headers={'x-api-key': api_key})
```

**and getting this error**

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state my_lambda' (entered at the event id #2). The JSONPath '$$.Job.Id' specified for the field 'job_id.$' could not be found in the input '{\"Execution\":{\"Id\":\"arn:aws:states:us-west-2:935463345537:execution:on-demand-scan-flow-orchestrator:fd51a151-70d4-4d8a-b203-fe3ea5ce7269\",\"Input\":{\"data\":{\"job_id\":30150908},\"apiInfo\":{\"httpMethod\":\"POST\",\"apiKey\":\"zWLyDJkvnSWaiK4Rf\"}},\"Name\":\"fd51a151-70d4-4d8a-b203-fe3ea5ce7269\",\"RoleArn\":\"arn:aws:iam::935463345537:role/on-demand-scan-stack-myorchestratorR-1LCG5GDN3L44F\",\"StartTime\":\"2022-07-06T14:05:17.175Z\"},\"StateMachine\":{\"Id\":\"arn:aws:states:us-west-2:935463345537:stateMachine:my-orchestrator\",\"Name\":\"my-function\"},\"State\":{\"Name\":\"my-function\",\"EnteredTime\":\"2022-07-06T14:05:17.222Z\",\"RetryCount\":0}}'"
}
```

Comment: Are you using CDK to stand up the resource or programmatically invoke it?

Comment: @smac2020 yes created step function using cdk . this one is  1st step of stepfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$$.` prefix refers to the execution's [Context Object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html).  It has no `Job` key.  Perhaps you mean `$$.Execution.Id`?  If `Job.Id` is part of your own defined input, prefix it with (a single) `$.`.

Comment: actually on first step I want my lambda to return execution  id , but it's giving error to expect execution id . I did same as of previous question answer you told to do,

Comment: In this one , I just want to call start and want to get just execution id. how i can do ? thanks in advance    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72806518/how-can-i-use-a-task-state-multiple-times-in-aws-step-functions-using-the-cdk/72807604?noredirect=1#comment128633015_72807604

Comment: @back-new Your Lambda tasks won't know the Step Function's Execution Id unless you pass it in the function's payload.  Add something like `execution_id.$: $$.Execution.Id` to your payload prop if your Lambda needs it.

Comment: hi sir can you please look at this issue ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901412/validationexception-on-aws-step-function-api-gateway