# validation errors detected: Value at 'output' failed to satisfy constraint aws step function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

My payload is something like this and sending it using python code payload is :

```
in_data = {"output": json.dumps({"Payload": {"execution_id": execution_id}}), "taskToken": task_token}
data = requests.post(url , json=in_data )
print( data.json() )
```

my step function code look like this :

and when I am sending to my `SendTaskSuccess` step it is giving me this error

```
"body-json": {
        "__type": "com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException",
        "message": "2 validation errors detected: Value at 'output' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null; Value null at 'taskToken' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"
    },
other-keys-here
}
```

kindly guide what could be issue please.

**EDIT**

my step function look like this  and It's waiting in state 1 and waiting fot task token . I am trying to send task token and getting error

```
{
  "StartAt": "process",
  "States": {
    "on-demand-scan-pre-process": {
      "Next": "source-scan-metadata-extraction",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke.waitForTaskToken",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:arn:function:process-new",
        "Payload": {
          "payload.$": "$",
          "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
          "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
        }
      }
    },
    "metadata-extraction": {
      "Next": "Done",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "Lambda.ServiceException",
            "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
            "Lambda.SdkClientException"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 2,
          "MaxAttempts": 6,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "Type": "Task",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:arn:function:metadata-extraction",
        "Payload": {
          "payload.$": "$",
          "execution_id.$": "$$.Execution.Id",
          "taskToken.$": "$$.Task.Token"
        }
      }
    },
    "Done": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```